# Arima. Python. График по координатам

Tags: python

Я новичок в питоне и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно предсказать поведение графика по модели ARIMA. Нашел такой код в интернете, но он не дает нужного результата в моем случае.

```
y = pm.datasets.load_wineind()
train, test = train_test_split(y, train_size=150)

# Fit your model
model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12)

# make your forecasts
forecasts = model.predict(test.shape[0])  # predict N steps into the future

# Visualize the forecasts (blue=train, green=forecasts)
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
plt.plot(x[:150], train, c='blue')
plt.plot(x[150:], forecasts, c='green')
plt.show()
```

Задача заключается в построении графика прогноза по координатам(144 штуки), которые записываются в файл и затем уже используются для прогнозирования.Высылаю весь код для общего понятия задания:

```
import matplotlib
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pmdarima as pm
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame



class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = ""
        self.x = ""

    def Fill(self):
        n = 144
        xlist = []
        with open("x.txt", "w") as xlist:
            for i in range(n):
                xlist.writelines(str(i) + '\n')
        xlist.close()

        ylist = []
        with open("y.txt", "w") as ylist:
            for i in range(n):
                ylist.writelines(str(random.randint(1, 99)) + '\n')
        ylist.close()


     def Screen(self):
        n = 144
        x = np.array([])
         with open("x.txt") as xlist:
            for line in xlist:
                 x = np.loadtxt(xlist.readlines(int()))
                 self.fx = x

        y = np.array([])
        with open("y.txt") as ylist:
            for line in ylist:
                y = np.loadtxt(ylist.readlines(int()))
                self.fy = y
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()

    def Arima(self):
        with open('y.txt', 'r') as infile, open('y.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
            lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerows(lines)

        y = []
        with open('y.csv') as f:
            for line in f:
                y = np.loadtxt(f.readlines(int()))


        train, test = train_test_split(y, train_size=140)

        model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12)

        forecasts = model.predict(test.shape[0])

        x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
        plt.plot(x[:140], train, c='blue')
        plt.plot(x[140:], forecasts, c='green')
        plt.show()




gra = Graph()
gra.Fill()
gra.Screen()
gra.Arima()
```

Предполагаю, что мне нужно сделать свой dataset, откуда и будут браться данные для прогнозирования, но как это сделать, не знаю
Вот сам график:

[image: График]

Answer (score 1):

Вчера вы жаловались, что не можете найти нужную документацию. Я вам ее нашел и привел ссылку. Сегодня вы не можете разобраться с самим методом. Я бы советовал все-таки идти в обратном порядке, от теории к конкретным функциям реализации. Но тем не менее.

Вот еще несколько ссылочек, которые вам помогут и с ARIMA разобраться и на примеры реализации у других посмотреть:

https://datascienceplus.com/forecasting-with-arima-part-i/

https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-forecasting-with-seasonal-arima

https://towardsdatascience.com/arima-forecasting-in-python-90d36c2246d3

https://habr.com/ru/post/207160/

Но что-то мне подсказывет, что вам начинать стоит еще раньше, с понятия временного ряда. Это такой набор данных, который строго зависит от времени. А у вас в вашем примере о времени вообще ничего нет. И что вы хотите предсказывать, тем более моделью ARIMA, если данные у вас генерируются датчиком равномерно распределенных случайных чисел?

На всякий случай:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-time-series-analysis-with-pandas/